# Structure initialization

Tags: c++, struct, initialization

I have used the following structure

```
template <typename Item>
struct TSet
{
    typedef std::set <int, comparator <Item>  >  Type;
};
```

as a data member of the the structure

```
template <typename Item>
struct TObject
{ 
   int code; 
   ...
   typename TSet <Item> ::Type indices;

   TObject ( const List <Item> *list ) : code( 0 ), indices ( list ) {}
 };
```

where

```
 template <typename Item>
 struct TList
 {
    typedef std::vector <Item> Type;
 };

template <typename Item>
class List
{
    private:
            typename TList <Item>::Type items;
};
```

But I have changed the data model to

```
template <typename Item> 
class TSet : public std::set <int, comparator <Item>  >
{
};

template <typename Item>
struct TObject
{ 
  int code; 
  ...
  typename TSet <Item> indices;

  TObject ( const List <Item> *list ) : code ( 0 ), indices ( list ) {} //Error: Can not convert parameter 1 const List <Item> to const TSet <Item>
 };
```

and there are problems with the structure initialization.

```
Error: Can not convert parameter 1 const List <Item> to const TSet <Item>
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: what is the List class? how would you construct a TSet<Item> from a const List<Item>* ?

Comment: I can't see what `List` is. Also, don't publicly inherit from standard containers. Someone, sometime will try to use it polymorphically and break your code.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you expect a conversion from `List` to `TSet` if you did not write one?  Also, the type of `indices` needs a `typename` on the front since it is a dependent type.

Comment: Could you give me a short example please?

Comment: I rewrote the declaration to typename TSet <Item> indices. List of items is used only for initialization of the comparator comparator <Item>. I am not sure that I need a conversion function...

Comment: @Robo: Looking at the new code, how would you expect `List<Item>` to be converted to `TSet<Item>` in your initialization?  There is no conversion operator or constructor for that.

Comment: But the old model also does not have any conversion function: indices ( list ) initialize only comparator (and it worked)...